ArcGIS Experience Builder - Combining Multiple Experiences
I'm working on a few different experiences using Esri's Experience Builder. Each experience has multiple pages that can be moved to from the menu widget. However, once complete, I need to be able to see all pages from each experience in the menu of a single one. Either by linking to them somehow outside of the current experience or merging them together once complete.
Is there a way to make this happen without building all of them within the same experience from the start?

Option A:

Create your own navigation menu using an anchored window. You could populate this with every link you want, including external ones. You would have to recreate this same menu across all of your experiences though.

Option B:

Create a fourth experience as a wrapper for all of the experiences. Individually iframe each page into its own page in the new experience and use the included navigation widget. This may or may not work depending on how you have set things to interact within your experience.

